# How to Extract the second word for each element in a string. (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, split, list-comprehension

Update: So a few of the strings in the list are only one word long and that is why it is throwing the index error.

I am trying to extract the second word in each element and save it to the list. I am getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` when running this.

`df_list = [isplit()[0] for i in df_list]` works to extract the first word but running the same code on index=1 does not seem to work.

```
    df_list = ['ACTVIVTY PLN CMD', 'ACTIVITY CUST COST', 'OPTY TWO ORG', 'ORG PLN ACTION', 'ACTIVITY', 'PLN ORG']

    df_list = [i.split()[1] for i in df_list]
```

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Works for me, can you show the error code?

Comment: In your real list, do you have any string that is only 1 word long? The error seems to point in that direction but the example strings you gave all have 3 words.

Comment: Works, as well, seems like we don't have the same dataset, maybe some string lacks a 2nd word.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with only one word, `i.split()` will give you a length 1 list and then trying to get the item at position 1 (2nd item) will give you an error.

```
df_list = ['ACTVIVTY PLN CMD', 'ACTIVITY CUST COST', 'OPTY TWO ORG', 'ACTIVITY']
```

There are multiples ways to check for this, for example:

```
df_list = [word for words in df_list for i, word in enumerate(words.split()) if i == 1]
```

Or:

```
df_list = [words.split()[1] for words in df_list if len(words.split()) > 1]
```

Or yuou could also look for the character that splits words (usually spaces, but it may also be some other characters as tabs, etc).

Performancewise, the first has a second for-loop, the second has two calls to split() for each string and the third one would have to check the string for the pressence of those characters, so there's no clear winner without testing.